# Beacon general information

Tags: android, ibeacon-android, google-beacon-platform

first of all i would like to say that beacons seems to be something great and usable, i am very enthusiastic still i saw it for the first time.
Now, i would like to try them and to make an Android app, but i'm confused about some things that i didn't found it clearly on internet:

1. Are beacons available already?
2. How much does a beacon cost?
3. Does it need to be charged ?
4. How much time can a beacon work without charging?
5. Do i need to setup every device for interaction with it?
6. Can i implement beacon in Unity App ?
7. Is there any tutorials about using it?

I know, post is a little big, but i would be very glad if i will found here answers. Have a nice day! ;)

Answer (score 0):

Are beacons available already?
yes, check out the internet.. radius networks, kontakt.io, estimote etc., you could also hit Alibaba, or buy a raspberry pi and a bluetooth dongle

How much does a beacon cost?
cheap. Small beacons could be as little $1 each, but these have drawbacks like non-replaceable batteries and short range, Bluetooth 5 beacon could be more expensive, but these can cover a 1km radius (personally I think that's pointless). Typically expect around $30 for a "good" or top-tier beacon company's primary beacon choice. If you buy bulk you get cheaper, but you might want to experiment with a few different kinds before you do that. Our company bought like 300 at one stage and we might need to replace them with a different manufacturer now

Does it need to be charged ?
some have replaceable batteries, some are only available to be plugged in, some are just disposable - you need to track that yourself

How much time can a beacon work without charging?
it can't - you may be thinking of NFC here - a Bluetooth radio/antenna requires more power than you might think (but probably less than both of us think to be honest), however it needs a dedicated power source both to transmit and receive data

Do i need to setup every device for interaction with it?
no, you make an app that listens for it. Well.. there are actually lot of options, however, not with straightforward detection/processing. Eddystone promotes a notion of "the Physical Web", which is like using URLs sent by Eddystone beacons to show you the right content, or iPhones actually have more built in support for some (mainly) retail use cases. Android is great because you can do so much in the background, and foreground services give you a lot more say about how and when you are stopped. You should also be aware that 4/5/6/7 all have different caveats around scanning/receiving, but most of the differences will/should be absorbed by any SDK you might use

Can i implement beacon in Unity App ?
certainly, just find a use case (AR/VR and a drone with a beacon for a Dragon? :O)

Is there any tutorials about using it?
so many, google about, but I would recommend starting with Radius Network's [Android Beacon Library.](https://github.com/AltBeacon/android-beacon-library)(This uses Altbeacon, but is VERY easily changed to work with iBeacon and even Eddystone, also it's free and these guys know their stuff). Also, there are many beacon apps you should download as the consistency is not guaranteed across devices, and a few apps have a few different features that you might want for debugging. Try Locate Beacon (by Radius) NRF Toolbox and basically any other BLE app with a decent score - it can be really good to cross reference the hits when funny stuff starts happening.

A lot of people talk about Beacons and managing them as if it's more complex than it is, you have an object that just screams an ID every X milliseconds, you hear that, you do something with it, once, every X seconds, or whatever you want

I would say you should get very familiar with the difference between BLE/ Bluetooth Smart and regular Bluetooth that interacts via a GATT server. With beacons you're essentially just listening to a peripheral device that advertises in a set format. As the developer, it is up to you to take this and make it meaningful for your user

Comment: also be aware that each device can perform VASTLY differently to each other, and the OS can have an impact due to some changes between SDK releases. For instance, make a lovely basic beacon app on, say, a Samsung tablet running Kitkat, then try it on a Lollipop nexus 4 hahaha you'll have a laugh at how terrible the nexus is - this is something you'll have to stay on top of if you release an app. Some devices just DO NOT play well with BLE, sometimes it's because the Antenna (which does WiFi and BT) is just very poorly managed. Newer phones and SDK releases seem to be more stable

Comment: Radius' tutorials for the Android Beacon Library live [here](http://altbeacon.github.io/android-beacon-library/) - it's very basic but should be enough for you to see how easy it will be to create a structure that will allow you to work with Beacons